# How to set users from web app in gmail add-in?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I developed gmail add in. It show button using apps script and button is open link.
My add-in consists of gmail composeTrigger.

```
function onGmailComposeTrigger(e) {
    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button1OpenLink1 = CardService.newOpenLink()
      .setUrl(`<MyDomain>/Home/Index/${scriptPrpt.getProperty('email')}`)
      .setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.OVERLAY).setOnClose(CardService.OnClose.RELOAD);

    let cardSection1ButtonList1Button1 = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Button 1')
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT)
        .setOpenLink(cardSection1ButtonList1Button1OpenLink1);

    let cardSection1ButtonList1 = CardService.newButtonSet()
        .addButton(cardSection1ButtonList1Button1);

    let cardSection1 = CardService.newCardSection()
        .addWidget(cardSection1ButtonList1);

    let card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .addSection(cardSection1)
        .build();
    return card;
}
```

Click the button to invoke the web app as a pop up. The webapp is a single page from which you can configure and save recipients.

The problem is that I cannot directly insert users that are currently saved in the new message that is already displayed. So now, I create a new draft on webapp and use ID to use window.open in JavaScript to call the following to display a new tab.

```
window.close();
window.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=' + <draftID>);
```

Is there a way to modify recipients directly to already open message other than to display a new draft window with url calls?